# Calling C code from frame in JAVA

Tags: java, swing, java-native-interface

I'm really new to java programming therefore I apologize in advance if this sounds like a stupid question.

I'm using JNI to invoke C code by creating a Swing JFrame and displays it. The code is fairly simple, and the Java-code is working fine if I set frame visibility to false (i.e. the "hello" method is called) whereas when I set frame visibility to true, nothing happens(i.e. the "hello" method is not called).

Test.java

```
public class Test extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    public static Container root;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */

     public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Test frame = new Test();

            new JNIServer().hello("world");  // where hello is native method
            frame.setVisible(true);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();        
        }
    }       
}
```

JNIServer.java

```
public class JNIServer{

    public native void hello(String name);  

    static {  
         System.out.println("Inload library");
         System.loadLibrary("JNI_Lib");     
    }  
}
```

Comment: Is this your complete program? And what does JNI_Lib look like? Note that in a real program, you'd take much more care with threading, making sure that Swing code is launched on the Swing event thread and that the native code is run in its own thread.

Comment: I have not posted the C code otherwise yes, that is all.

Comment: This isn't a complete program, or a complete question.

Comment: @Alex.. I haven't posted C file as I have tried to print some messages in it just to ensure that I am able to access C code from java

Comment: @Freek.. This tutorial is not related to my problem. I am repeating my question: I want to hit C code from Java through JNI using GUI.

Comment: I am able to access C method only when I set frame visibility to false. Why I am not able to access C code when I set frame visibility to true using GUI

Comment: @shilpy - In the tutorial a Java program calls a C function called `Java_HelloWorld_helloFromC` that prints a string: `printf("Hello from C!\n");`. The only difference from your example that I can see is that you are doing something with a frame. I see no reason why that should interfere; very strange. What happens when you add a `JButton` to your GUI and call your C function from an action listener of that button? That way, the frame is already visible when you start the C function.

Comment: @Freek... Behaviour is same in that case as well. I have already added a JButton and called C function from an action listener of that button  but still C code is not executing. In JNIServer.java static method is called and then nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

As [Hovercraft Full Of Eels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/522444/hovercraft-full-of-eels) already suggested, you could try using a separate thread. I would also try adding some more println statements, to pinpoint the cause of the problem.

In an attempt to reproduce your problem, I have tested on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit with Java SE 1.8.0_66-b17 (java -version) and gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4 (gcc --version).

To simplify things a bit, I did not pass a `String` parameter to the `hello` method/function, to skip that conversion for the moment. These are the source files I used to test:

```
// Test.java

import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test extends JFrame {
    private JPanel contentPane;
    public static Container root;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Test frame = new Test();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            frame.callNativeFunction();

            System.out.println("Test.main - before setting frame visible");
            frame.setVisible(true);
            System.out.println("Test.main - after setting frame visible");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void callNativeFunction() {
        Thread nativeFunctionThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Test.run - before calling hello.");
                new JNIServer().hello();  // where hello is native method
                System.out.println("Test.run - after calling hello.");
            }
        });

        nativeFunctionThread.start();
    }
}


// JNIServer.java

public class JNIServer {
    public native void hello();

    static {  
        System.out.println("Inload library");
        System.loadLibrary("JNI_Lib");
    }  
}


// JNIServer.h (generated)

/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class JNIServer */

#ifndef _Included_JNIServer
#define _Included_JNIServer
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     JNIServer
 * Method:    hello
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_JNIServer_hello
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif


// JNI_Lib.c

#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_JNIServer_hello(JNIEnv * environment,
                                            jobject java_object) {
    printf("Hello from C!\n");
}
```

To build the application, I ran these commands:

```
javac Test.java
java Test
javah JNIServer

gcc -fPIC -o libJNI_Lib.so -shared -I /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include -I /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/linux JNI_Lib.c -lc

java -Djava.library.path=. Test
```

This was the output from the `java -Djava.library.path=. Test` command:

```
Test.main - before setting frame visible
Test.run - before calling hello.
Inload library
Hello from C!
Test.run - after calling hello.
Test.main - after setting frame visible
```

The highly anticipated "Hello from C!" was printed. A (very small) frame was visible. (You can use the `JFrame.setBounds` method to resize and position a frame.)

**Edit: using Eclipse**

Although it should be possible to have a combined [Java and C project in Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/788196/), I suggest to start with a smaller step: use two separate Eclipse projects (or even smaller: create a Java project that refers to the library created by your CLI C project). If that is working, you can work on a combined Eclipse project.

The CLI example above has the `java.library.path` pointing to the directory with the libJNI_Lib.so file. For a Java project in Eclipse, you can select the Run | Run Configurations... menu, if necessary select the Java project in the left panel, select the Arguments tab in the right panel, and add "-Djava.library.path=." (without quotes) to the VM arguments. See for example this screenshot of the Run Configurations dialog:

[image: Screenshot of the Run Configurations dialog]

Comment: Which version of the Java JDK and which C compiler do you use? On what operating system do you run?

Comment: I am using JDK1.8, gcc compiler and ubuntu as OS. I have tried it on linuxmint as well.

Comment: Suggestion for closing your Swing application: call `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` after creating the frame. This makes sure your program is closed when you close the frame.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This has helped me as now "Hello from C " message got printed when I close the frame. But stll my motto is not fulfilled. I have tried your suggested code as well but still facing the same problem. I am not getting the same output as you got. "Hello from C was not printed simultaneously"

Comment: Could you add your output to the question? For me, the "Hello from C!" message is printed before the frame is made visible (and before I close the frame).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I am trying to execute the code in Eclipse... I have tried your code on CLI it is working fine. I am getting the same output as you are saying.   I think on CLI we are placing C file and JAVA file in same folder. On Eclipse I have made two different projects, 1 is java project and other is C project. Might be this is causing the issue. I have no idea how can I combine C and JAVA code in 1 project on Eclipse. Could you please help?